# Supabase error when trying to upload image

Tags: postgresql, supabase

When I try to upload an image to supabase to a public bucket I created I get the following error

`new row violates row-level security policy for table \"objects\`

I am wondering why that is for a public bucket?

Answer (score 4):

I found out that there are also policys for storage, which are pretty straight forward. Since I did not read about this functionality in the official docs I thought I might save some people some time search around.

Under "Storage" you can find a policies section.

[image: look out for the policies section]

Answer (score 0):

As additional information, you have to give the INSERT RLS policy on the bucket objects.

These are my configurations which work for me:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNkIS.png)

you need to use the secret not the public key to upload files open this image in the top